# PHP Two Foreach Loops Multiply values from each loop on each iteration

Tags: php, foreach, multiplication

I have these two loops

```
          foreach($decode_pricing->items as $items=>$item) {
              $cost .= number_format($item->pricing[0]->cost, 2);
          }

          foreach($qty_ea as $ea) {
              $ff .= $ea;
          }
```

top foreach outputs

```
44.8244.8244.82
```

formatted

```
44.82
44.82
44.82
```

bottom foreach outputs

```
121
```

formatted

```
1
2
1
```

How can I multiply the top value with the bottom value on each iteration of the loop?

The output I want is

```
44.82
89.64
44.82
```

Comment: Can you show us the structure of your input `qty_ea` and `$decode_pricing->items`. var_dump them in order to allow us to see the structure. Another question, you inputs are always the same size?

Comment: what do you mean by same size? The quantity and dollar amount will be different on each transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
 foreach($decode_pricing->items as $key => $item) {
          $cost .= $qty_ea[$key] * number_format($item->pricing[0]->cost, 2);
      }
```

Assuming your both of your arrays are Numeric.